# How do I plot a solution of a differential equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am having trouble generating a plot for a solution to my differential equations. I always end up with just blank axes.

```
Clear["Global`*"] 
Remove["Global`*"]
m x''[t] == -k m x'[t];
m y''[t] == -k m y'[t] - m g;
U == v Cos[\[Theta]];
V == v Sin[\[Theta]];
soln = DSolve[{m x''[t] == -k m x'[t], m y''[t] == -k m y'[t] - m g, 
  x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == U, y'[0] == V}, {x[t], y[t]}, 
 t][[1]] // Simplify;
soln
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

The solution comes out fine but the graph always comes out blank. I'm sure I'm making some rookie mistake somewhere and would appreciate if someone can point it out.

Comment: You can change `ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. soln, ...]` and in order to get a plot you need to specify numerical values for your parameters.

Comment: My [answer to an unrelated question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16229/revolution-plot-with-2-variable/16238#16238) gives an example of plotting solutions to `NDSolve`.

Comment: `Clear` then `Remove` is redundant. `Clear` will remove all [rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52) associated with a symbol, but the symbol remains known. `Remove` does that and removes the symbol from the "known" symbols list. Personally, I use `Clear`, and sometimes [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearAll.html), if I've set `Attributes` or attached `Messages` to the symbol, and reserve `Remove` for when I have to deal with [shadowing](http://wolfram.com/xid/0278f71b9yy6-ed6dbj).

Comment: (cont'd) I also set each notebook to have its own [`Context`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/854/52), so that multiple notebooks do not conflict with each other.

Answer (score 7):

In order plot your solution you have to replace all parameters with explicit values. One possible way is to use `Manipulate`.

```
m x''[t] == -k m x'[t];
m y''[t] == -k m y'[t] - m g;
U == v Cos[\[Theta]];
V == v Sin[\[Theta]];
soln = DSolve[{m x''[t] == -k m x'[t], m y''[t] == -k m y'[t] - m g, 
  x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == U, y'[0] == V}, {x[t], y[t]}, 
 t][[1]] // Simplify;

With[{expr = {x[t], y[t]} /. soln},
 Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[expr, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-5, 5}}],
  {{k, 1}, .1, 5},
  {{g, 3}, 1, 10},
  {{U, 6}, 2, 10},
  {V, 5, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

1. I believe the main issue for you is that *Mathematica* does not know what `x[t]` and `y[t]` are in your `ParametricPlot` command. An excellent way to solve this is by using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll&lang=en) (a.k.a. `/.`) with the [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html?q=Rule&lang=en)s already included in the solution produced by `DSolve`.
2. Ensure that your parameters (e.g. `U` and `V`) are assigned values with [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html?q=Set&lang=en) (`=`); do not use [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html?q=Equal&lang=en) (`==`) here, which is an operator used to define equations and do logical comparisons of two expressions.
3. Assign values (using `Set`) to all of your parameters, as mentioned by user halirutan.

I propose the following improved code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
m = k = v = θ = g = 1;
m x''[t] == -k m x'[t];
m y''[t] == -k m y'[t] - m g;
U = v Cos[θ];
V = v Sin[θ];
soln = DSolve[{m x''[t] == -k m x'[t], m y''[t] == -k m y'[t] - m g, 
x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == U, y'[0] == V}, {x[t], y[t]}, t][[1]];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

As a further example, I've included a direction field and a parametric plot of a specific solution for a different, first-order differential equation. The specific solution corresponds to a single value (in this case `C[1] = 0`) for the constant of integration which is in the general solution.

```
soln=DSolve[y'[x]==(x^2)/(1-y[x]^2),y[x],x];
plotone=ParametricPlot[{x,y[x]/.soln[[1]]/.C[1]->0},{x,-10,10}, PlotStyle->{Red, Thickness[0.01]}];
plottwo=StreamPlot[{(1 - y^2),x^2},{x,-10,10}, {y,-10,10}, VectorScale->.2, StreamStyle-> Blue];
Show[plottwo,plotone]
```

[image]